# Spring boot + hibernate search: entityManagerFactory dependency error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I'm stuck with this problem during startup in my Spring Boot application.

The outcome is this:

> WARN 8532 --- [           main] o.h.s.a.i.LuceneEmbeddedAnalyzerStrategy : HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified: using LUCENE_CURRENT.
>   WARN 8532 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with > name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: > org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
>   INFO 8532 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   INFO 8532 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   ERROR 8532 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of > init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:** **org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;**
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.4.RELEASE]
>           at com.closdeal.restService.RestServiceApplication.main(RestServiceApplication.java:20) [classes!/:na]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [closdeal-rest-service-1.0.2.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [closdeal-rest-service-1.0.2.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [closdeal-rest-service-1.0.2.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [closdeal-rest-service-1.0.2.jar:na]
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:124) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:890) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
>           ... 24 common frames omitted

These are the dependencies declared in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    //Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-data', version: '4.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-hal-browser', version: '3.0.0.RELEASE'

    //Hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.11.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '5.2.11.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search-orm', version: '5.8.1.Final'
//    compile group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api', version: '1.0.0.Final'

    //JSON
    compile("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl")

    //Bases de datos
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.7-dmr'

    //Utilerías varias
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'net.glxn', name: 'qrgen', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'com.vividsolutions', name: 'jts', version: '1.13'


    //Test
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0")
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.0")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

When I've checked the signature of the getProperties method of EntityManagerFactory class (into hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar) is this:

```
public Map<String, Object> getProperties();
```

I don't know why expects this method to return a Properties object instead a map. This jar is quite old (from 2013 remains unchanged); and it seems there's no other jar which declares the EntityManagerFactory class into the classpath. I've checked other questions similar to this, and they all point to a duplicate of this class into classpath, but it seems this is not the problem here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

-- UPDATE: I've changed the gradle dependencies adding the dependencyManagement section and editing the dependencies according to Guillaume's suggestion:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Spring
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-data'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-rest-hal-browser'

    //Hibernate
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.1.10.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-spatial', version: '5.1.10.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search', version: '5.6.3.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search-engine', version: '5.6.3.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-search-orm', version: '5.6.3.Final'

    //JSON
    compile("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl")

    //Bases de datos
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.7-dmr'

    //Utilerías varias
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'net.glxn', name: 'qrgen', version: '1.4'
    compile group: 'com.vividsolutions', name: 'jts', version: '1.13'


    //Test
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0")
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.0.0")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

It seems to work properly. I'll check it and confirm it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICS Spring Boot is still based on Hibernate ORM 5.0.x. See https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.7.RELEASE.pom .

This explains why you have this error.

It might work with Hibernate ORM 5.1 too but 5.2 changes a lot of things.

So you should downgrade ORM to either the latest 5.0.x or try 5.1.x (at your own risk) and also downgrade Hibernate Search to the latest 5.6.x.

Comment: Guillaume, it seems to be that the problem! Check out the main question where I've explained in detail what I did based on your suggestion.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 1.5 does work with Hibernate ORM 5.2 / search 5.8, but you have to override all the dependencies. I suspect you only overrode some of them in your original configuration, and propbably had multiple versions of Hibernate ORM in your classpath.

I don't know how to do it with Gradle, but with Maven you have to override the `hibernate.version` property.

Here is an example with Maven, if that helps:

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-demos/blob/master/hibernate-search/hsearch-elasticsearch-wikipedia/pom.xml#L28